# Type parameter declaration must be an identifier

Tags: c#

```
interface IRepository<TEntity,Tid> where TEntity :class 
{
    int Insert(TEntity entity);
    int Delete(TEntity entity);
    TEntity GetById(Tid id);
    TEntity GetByFilters(TEntity entity);
    int Update(TEntity entity);        
}
```

Trying to implement

```
internal class Repository<XYZClass, string> : IRepository<XYZCLass, string> 
{    
    //...All interface methods    
}
```

Getting below error:

> type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type

Any Suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Repository` to be non-generic you need to specify both types:

```
internal class Repository : IRepository<XYZClass, string> { ... }
```

If you want `Repository` to be generic but specify that `TId` is a `string` you can use

```
internal class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity, string> where TEntity : class
{    
    //...All interface methods    
}
```

`string` is a type, not a generic type parameter.

Comment: Note that `XYZClass` is a concrete entity class. If the Entity type is still to be generic, then better to use `TEntity` and the type parameter name.

Comment: The second version does not seem to respect the reference type constraint required by the interface, so it would need its own constraint to compile, I guess. (See my answer.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - Thanks, I missed the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration should only include type parameters for those that are generic to those consuming the class.

In other words, if you implementation of IRepository sets the TEntity parameter to XYZClass and the TID parameter to string (ie a concrete class definition), then you should have:

```
internal class Repository : IRepository<XYZCLass, string> 
{    
    //...All interface methods    
}
```

If you wish to define one type and leave the other generic then:

```
internal class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity, string> 
{    
    //...All interface methods    
}
```

Otherwise, both types should still be left open:

```
internal class Repository<TEntity,TID> : IRepository<TEntity, TID> 
{    
    //...All interface methods    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want a base class constraint?

```
internal class Repository<TYourEntity> : IRepository<TYourEntity, string>
    where TYourEntity : XyzClass
{    
    //...All interface methods    
}
```

Note that this constraint means that the constraint on the interface (the reference type constraint `TEntity : class`) is satisfied.

---

For completeness, the other "legal" interpretations of what you meant (also in other answers already), are:

```
// don't constrain generic parameter, just name it TXyz (TXyz is "declared" here)

internal class Repository<TXyz> : IRepository<TXyz, string>
    where TXyz : class
{    
    //...All interface methods    
}
```

and:

```
// make class non-generic (the type XyzClass exists and is declared elsewhere)

internal class Repository : IRepository<XyzClass, string>
{    
    //...All interface methods    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thus repository is not generic (it is implementation of repository interface parametrized with concrete classes):

```
internal class Repository : IRepository<XYZCLass, string>
```